# A-Z view for a document library

Tags: web-part

Is it possible to create a webpart for document library that will look like this?

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU952.gif

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EU952.gif

Answer (score 5):

Try this http://kwizcom.blogspot.com/2007/06/creating-a-z-filter-for-list.html, it may help resolve your issue.

Comment: +1. To add: 1) You can use document library view with grouping by the calculated column, without creating a custom webpart. 2) Probably, it would be better to use `=UPPER(LEFT([Title],1))` formula, to ensure that all the letters are uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

I used this [jquery library](https://github.com/iHwy/jQuery-ListNav) recently to create a similar effect.  Very easy to use.  I simply created a DVWP that output my content in the format I wanted an in an unordered list.

Then using this, it creates the alphapet list automagically:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myList').listnav({
        initLetter: 'a',
        noMatchText: 'There are no courses schedled starting with this letter.  Try a different letter.',
        showCounts: false,
        prefixes: ['the','a']
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: sadly, the link is broken now after 7 years

Comment: 15 seconds to google jQuery listnav plugin leads to the github page, https://github.com/iHwy/jQuery-ListNav

Comment: thx for updating the link @Eric